# Exporting In-Memory HSQL Database Content as SQL During Maven Build

Tags: maven-2, maven, hsqldb

During a Maven build's integration test phase I am populating an in-memory HSQL database based on the performed tests. Afterwards, I would like to capture this state by exporting the database content as SQL statements (for later import).

Is there some Maven plugin or command line tool suitable for this task? For MySQL we are using mysqldump, so I am basically looking for an equivalent for HSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HSQLDB use:

```
SCRIPT <filepath>
```

Example:

```
SCRIPT '/opt/dump/mydb.script'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the [dbunit plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/export-mojo.html), for one, which should work for a variety of databases.

Comment: Thanks! I assume you are referring to the dbunit:export goal. I was not aware that this supports exporting as SQL (but just as XML) - for legacy reasons, I need to export it as SQL, though.

The docs just state:
    format (Default: xml)
      DataSet file format